# Setting a property key for a node based on another node in a relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to find a way to set a new property for a node based on the property of another node.

I have set a relationship between them to see if that will help but so far to no avail.

```
match (s:Service) - [sv:SERVICE_FOR] -> (i:CircuitID)
where (s:Service {opp_service:'11'})
set i.service_type = "FIA"
```

so far it has just been endless errors.

Comment: You don't make it clear what property you want to set, or what value from the other node you want to use. In any case please read the Cypher documentation for how to use [SET](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/set/)

Answer (score -1):

//Update a property for a node based on another node in a relationship

```
match (n:Service)-[:SERVICE_FOR]->(i:CircuitID)
where n.opp_service = '11'
```

Comment: This doesn't look like an answer. You're not setting a property value the the value of another node's property. If this is meant to be another example of your attempt, please add it to the description of your question and delete this answer.